# defining makefile variables multiple times

Tags: linux, unix, makefile, gnu-make

I read the [Using Variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Using-Variables.html) section of the GNU make documentation but couldn't understand how make variables are expanded in make rules when they are defined several times.

See, for example, the following short makefile:

```
.PHONY: run
run: a b

TARGET := a

$(TARGET):
    echo $(TARGET)
    touch $@

TARGET := b

$(TARGET):
    echo $(TARGET)
    touch $@
```

which yields the following output when running `make`:

```
echo b
b
touch a
echo b
b
touch b
```

It seems that there is a target for `a`, and the automatic variable `$@` is indeed `a`. But echoing the `TARGET` variable, which is the target name as well, prints `b`... What's going on here?
I'd appreciate any help, preferably with linking to the docs, that clarifies this behavior.

Other questions that are probably related:

1. Is the makefile read only once when `make` is invoked?
2. Are the target *names* expanded when the makefile is read or later?
3. Are the target *rules* expanded when the makefile is read or later?

Note: using recursively expanded variable (that is, changing `:=` to `=`) doesn't change the output in the above example.

Comment: I don't have a doc reference to back this up, but I think 1) yes, 2) the names are expanded as Make reads the file, so the name of the first rule is `a` and the name of the second is `b`, 3) the recipes (the commands within the rules) are expanded only when the rules are executed, by which time `TARGET` is `b`.

Comment: @Beta that's entirely correct, I guess you should make it an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The information you're looking for is found in the GNU make manual section [How make Reads a Makefile](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Reading-Makefiles.html).